# Python - matplotlib modify xticks for a "loglog" plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, loglog

I am plotting in log scale for each axis, but I don't want scientific notation for the x axis, so I modified it as follows:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter

a = np.array([10.**(-2), 10.**(-3), 5.*10**(-3),10.**(-4), 10.**(-6), 10.**(-7)])
b = np.array([16, 12.5, 14.5, 9.5, 8., 7.5])

axes = plt.subplot(111)

plt.loglog(a,b, 'k.',markersize=10,markerfacecolor='None',label='')

plt.ylim(10**(-6),10**(-1))
plt.xlim(5,30)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.15)
plt.legend(loc=2)
axes.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(FormatStrFormatter("%.0f"))
plt.show()
```

But, as you can see in the picture below, there is 10 in scientific notation amongst the x axis labels... I don't know how to suppress it and just have `10`...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ScalarFormatter` from `matplotlib.ticker`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.semilogx(range(100))
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter())
#ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter()) # for the y axis

fig.show()
```

[image]